# Remove leading and trailing zeroes

Tags: code-golf, array

Given a non-empty list/array containing only non-negative integers like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Output the list with trailing and leading zeroes removed.

The output for this would be:

```
[8, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1, 2]
```

Some other test cases:

```
[0, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0] > [4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] > nothing
[3, 4, 5, 0, 0] > [3, 4, 5]
[6] > [6]
```

Shortest code wins

Comment: Are the numbers non-negative integers only? I suggest you clarify that or add test cases with other numbers

Comment: Can we assume that there will be at least one leading and one trailing 0?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, only non-negative integers.

Comment: @DJMcGoathem No, it is possible that there is no leading or trailing 0

Comment: What constitutes nothing? I can think of several different things that are variations on nothing in Perl 6. `Nil` `()`/`[]` `slip()`/`Empty` `Any` `{}` some of them are undefined, some defined but singular, some that slip into other lists such that they don't increase the number of elements. ( There are as many different variations on `Any` as there are classes/types and roles )

Comment: Is it a coincidence that there are no integers over 10 or can we assume that all the numbers are going to be single-digit?

Comment: Huh. I was thinking about posting this the other day, actually. +1

Comment: Can we input/output the list as a delimited string? For example: `"0,4,1,2,0,1,2,4,0" => "4,1,2,0,1,2,4"` EDIT: Just noticed many languages do this already.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

Code:

```
t0
```

Explanation:

```
t   # Trim off...
 0  #  zero at both sides
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=dDA&input=&args=WzAsIDAsIDAsIDgsIDEsIDQsIDMsIDUsIDAsIDYsIDQsIDEsIDIsIDAsIDAsIDAsIDBd)

Comment: This works? Jeez. I thought the MATL answers were insane.

Comment: wut y no don do dis jelly

Comment: Of course Jelly beats every other guy out there almost every time...

Comment: Is Jelly used in actual businesses?

Comment: Man, I hope not

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6) 43

```js
a=>(f=a=>a.reverse().filter(x=>a|=x))(f(a))
```

**Less golfed**

```js
a=>{
  f=a=>a.reverse().filter(x=>a|=x) // reverse and remove leading 0
  // leverage js cast rules: operator | cast operands to integer
  // an array casted to integer is 0 unless the array is made of
  // a single integer value (that is ok for me in this case)
  return f(f(a)) // apply 2 times
}
```

**Test**

```js
F=a=>(f=a=>a.reverse().filter(x=>a|=x))(f(a))

function test(){
  var l=(I.value.match(/\d+/g)||[]).map(x=>+x)
  O.textContent=F(l)
}

test()
```

```css
#I { width:90%}
```

```html
<input id=I oninput='test()' value='0 0 1 3 7 11 0 8 23 0 0 0'>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Nice. `f=(a,r=f(a,a))=>r.reverse().filter(x=>a|=x)` is also 43 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## Retina, 12 bytes

```
^0 ?

)` 0$
```

The trailing linefeed is significant.

Thanks to [@Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) and [@FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman) for saving a few bytes.

[Try it online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XjAgPwoKKWAgMCQK&input=MCAwIDAgMSAyIDMgMCA0IDUgNiAwIDAgMA)

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, 13 bytes

```
l~{_{}#>W%}2*
```

With the array inputted.

Longer version:

```
l~             Puts input on the stack and parse as array
  {       }    Code block
   _           Duplicate the first thing on the stack
    {}#        Finds the index of the first non-0 value in the array, puts it on the stack
       >       Slices the array from that index
        W%     Reverses the array
           2*  Does the code block twice in total
```

Comment: I wish I could use the fact that converting to and from a base would remove leading zeros, but it looks like it's too long.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)), 29 bytes

```
t=f.f;f=reverse.dropWhile(<1)
```

Answer (score 5):

### Pyth, 4 bytes

```
.sQ0
```

Demo:

```
llama@llama:~$ pyth -c .sQ0
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5]
```

From [Pyth's `rev-doc.txt`](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/d0857326708284d884298464363e633e1390b190/rev-doc.txt#L365):

```
.s <seq> <any>
    Strip from A maximal prefix and suffix of A consisting of copies of B.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

Code:

```
0Û0Ü
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MMObMMOc&input=WzAsIDAsIDAsIDgsIDEsIDQsIDMsIDUsIDAsIDYsIDQsIDEsIDIsIDAsIDAsIDAsIDBd)

Explanation:

```
0Û    # Trim off leading zeroes
  0Ü  # Trim off trailing zeroes
```

Uses CP-1252 encoding.

Answer (score 5):

### Jelly, 10 bytes

```
Uo\U,o\PTị
```

This doesn't use the builtin.

```
Uo\U            Backward running logical OR
    ,           paired with
     o\         Forward running logical OR
       P        Product
        T       All indices of truthy elements
         ị      Index the input at those values.
```

Try it [here](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=VW9cVSxvXFBU4buL&input=&args=WzAsIDQsIDEsIDIsIDAsIDEsIDIsIDAsIDBd).

Answer (score 5):

## R, 43 bytes

```
function(x)x[cummax(x)&rev(cummax(rev(x)))]
```

or as read/write STDIN/STDOUT

```
x=scan();cat(x[cummax(x)&rev(cummax(rev(x)))])
```

---

This finds the cumulative maximum from the beginning and the end (reversed) string. The `&` operator converts these two vectors to logical one of the same size as `x`, (zeroes will always converted to `FALSE` and everything else to `TRUE`), this way it makes it possible to subset from `x` according to the met conditions.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica <s>34</s>  27 bytes

```
#//.{0,a___}|{a___,0}:>{a}&
```

This repeatedly applies replacement rules until such action fails to provide a new output.  7 bytes saved thanks to Alephalpha.

The first rule deletes a zero at the beginning; the second rule deletes a zero at the end of the array.

Comment: `#//.{0,a___}|{a___,0}:>{a}&`

Answer (score 4):

### 05AB1E, 4 bytes

```
0Û0Ü
```

Basically trimming leading then trailing zeroes of the input, given as an array.

[Try it online !](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MMObMMOc&input=WzAsIDAsIDAsIDgsIDEsIDQsIDMsIDUsIDYsIDQsIDEsIDIsIDAsIDAsIDAsIDBd)

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, <s>49</s> 44 bytes

```
->a{eval ?a+'.drop_while{|i|i<1}.reverse'*2}
```

Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for chopping off 5 bytes with a completely different method!

This just `drop`s the first element of the array `while` it's 0, reverses the array, repeats, and finally reverses the array to return it to the proper order.

Comment: Ouch. Now even a `.drop_while()` based solution would be shorter (if using 2 functions): `f=->a{a.drop_while{|i|i<1}.reverse};->a{f[f[a]]}`

Comment: Doh. No need for 2 functions, just some `eval` ugliness: `->a{eval ?a+'.drop_while{|i|i<1}.reverse'*2}`.

Comment: @manatwork Not sure why I didn't think of `<1`, anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 19 + 1 = 20 bytes

```
s/^(0 ?)+|( 0)+$//g
```

Requires `-p` flag:

```
$ perl -pE's/^(0 )+|( 0)+$//g' <<< '0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0'
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: @MartinBüttner I though about the same just after hitting [Add Comment], now I just need to figure out now to let markdown save my newline in a code block

Comment: Via evil HTML hacks. ;)

Comment: 17+1 bytes: `s/^0 | 0$//&&redo`

Comment: @Kenney That is beautiful :-) You should post that as an answer!

Comment: Thanks! My original was also 19+1 bytes but then I saw your answer which gave me an idea to shave off 2 more, so it's yours if you want it. Btw, your answer is actually 18+1 if you drop the `?` as in the example - but that won't reduce `"0"`..

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 9 bytes

```
2:"PtYsg)
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MjoiUHRZc2cp&input=WzAsIDQsIDEsIDIsIDAsIDEsIDIsIDQsIDBd)

#### Explanation

```
2:"     % For loop (do the following twice)
  P     %   Flip array. Implicitly asks for input the first time
  t     %   Duplicate
  Ys    %   Cumulative sum
  g     %   Convert to logical index
  )     %   Apply index
        % Implicitly end for
        % Implicitly display stack contents
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 38 bytes

```
$\.=$_}{$\=~s/^(0\n)*|(0\n)*\n$//gs
```

Run with `perl -p`, (3 bytes added for `-p`).

Accepts numbers on STDIN, one per line; emits numbers on STDOUT, one per line, as a well-behaved unix utility should.

Only treats numbers represented exactly by '0' as zeroes; it would be possible to support other representations with a few more bytes in the regex.

Longer version, still to be run with `-p`:

```
    # append entire line to output record separator
    $\.=$_
}{
    # replace leading and trailng zeroes in output record separator
    $\ =~ s/^(0\n)*|(0\n)*\n$//gs
    # output record separator will be implicitly printed
```

Expanded version, showing interactions with -p flag:

```
# implicit while loop added by -p
while (<>) {
    # append line to output record separator
    $\.=$_
}{ # escape the implicit while loop
    # replace leading and traling 
    $\=~s/^(0\n)*|(0\n)*\n$//gs
    # print by default prints $_ followed by
    # the output record separator $\ which contains our answer
    ;print # implicit print added by -p
} # implicit closing brace added by -p
```

Comment: Assuming you're running with `perl -E`, the `-p` flag usually is only counted as one byte, since there's only one extra byte different between that and `perl -pE`.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

```
a=>a.join(a="").replace(/(^0+|0+$)/g,a).split(a)
```

Where `a` is the array.

Comment: I think you need to make an anonymous function to take input: `a=>a.join(a="")...`.

Comment: This only handles integers properly when they're a single digit

Comment: @dev-null Done.

Comment: Still returning wrong for multi-digit integers. `[14]` will return `[1, 4]`.

Comment: Actually, I was (and am) still awaiting a reply to [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71877/remove-leading-and-trailing-zeroes/72003?noredirect=1#comment176320_71877). Anyway, I unfortunately don't see a way to do handle multi-digit integers using the same technique I've used for my answer and I don't think I'll be able to beat [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/72009/13486) anyway. I may try when I have the time, though.

Answer (score 3):

### Elixir, 77 bytes

```
import Enum
z=fn x->x==0 end
reverse(drop_while(reverse(drop_while(l,z)),z))
```

l is the array.

Edit:wah! copy/pasta fail. of course one has to import Enum, which raises the byte count by 12 (or use Enum.function_name, which will make it even longer).

Answer (score 3):

## Vitsy, 13 bytes

Vitsy is slowly getting better... (I'm coming for you Jelly. ಠ_ಠ)

```
1mr1m
D)[X1m]
```

This exits with the array on the stack. For readability, the TryItOnline! link that I have provided below the explanation will output a formatted list.

Explanation:

```
1mr1m
1m      Do the second line of code.
  r     Reverse the stack.
   1m   I'ma let you figure this one out. ;)

D)[X1m]
D       Duplicate the top item of the stack.
 )[   ] If the top item of the stack is zero, do the stuff in brackets.
   X    Remove the top item of the stack.
    1m  Execute the second line of code.
```

Note that this will throw a StackOverflowException for unreasonably large inputs.

[TryItOnline!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=MW1yMW1sXFtOYU9dCkQpW1gxbV0&input=&args=MA+MA+Mg+MQ+MA+MA)

Comment: Vitsy will get Jelly some day.

Comment: Add auto-bracket matching on EOL/EOF

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```js
a=>a.replace(/^(0 ?)*|( 0)*$/g,'')
```

Input and output are in the form of a space-delimited list, such as `"0 4 1 2 0 1 2 4 0"`.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 39 bytes

```
function(x)x[min(i<-which(x>0)):max(i)]
```

Four bytes shorter than [David Arenburg's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73745/59052). This implementation finds the first and last index in the array which is greater than zero, and returns everything in the array between those two indices.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 48 bytes

```
lambda a:map(int,''.join(map(str,a)).strip('0'))
```

Comment: While it works for the given test cases, it fails if the input array contains number 10 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
{↔a₁.h>0∧}ⁱ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuaaRx3LldISc4pT9ZRqH@7qrH24dcJ/oNyUxEdNjXoZdgZA@dpHjRsPbfr/P1oh2kBHAYIsdBQMdRRMdBSMdRRMdRTMwGygiBFMAQjF6oB1IMtAGCYISQN0DcZgaVOEgFmsQiwA)

The predicate fails in the case of "nothing".

```
  a₁.           Take the longest suffix of
 ↔              the input reversed
     h          the first element of which
      >0        is greater than 0
        ∧       (which is not the output).
{        }ⁱ²    Do it again.
```

If "nothing" has to be some actual value, like an empty list, it's only one more byte:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
{↔a₁.h>0∨Ė}ⁱ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv/pR25TER02Nehl2Bo86VhyZVvuoceOhTf//RytEG@goQJCFjoKhjoKJjoKxjoKpjoIZmA0UMYIpAKFYHbAOZBkIwwQhaYCuwRgsbYoQMItViAUA)

If the input can be assumed to contain only single digits, it's quite a bit shorter:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
c↔↔ℕ₁ẹ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuaaRx3LldISc4pT9ZRqH@7qrH24dcL/5EdtU0CoZeqjpsaHu3b@/x@tEG2gowBBFjoKhjoKJjoKxjoKpjoKZmA2UMQIpgCEYnXAOpBlIAwThKQBugZjsLQpQsAsViEWAA)

Answer (score 2):

### Dyalog APL, 15 bytes

```
{⌽⍵↓⍨+/0=+\⍵}⍣2

               ⍣2     Apply this function twice:
{             }       Monadic function:
           +\⍵        Calculate the running sum.
       +/0=           Compare to zero and sum. Number of leading zeroes.
   ⍵↓⍨               Drop the first that many elements from the array.
 ⌽                   Reverse the result.
```

Try it [here](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%7B%u233D%u2375%u2193%u2368+/0%3D+%5C%u2375%7D%u23632%290%200%203%201%200%200%204%201%205%209%200%200%200&run).

Comment: How about `{⌽⍵/⍨×+\⍵}⍣2`?

Answer (score 2):

## Vim 16 Keystrokes

```
i<input><esc>?[1-9]<enter>lD0d/<up><enter>
```

The input is to be typed by the user between `i` and `esc`, and does not count as a keystroke. This assumes that there will be at least one leading and one trailing zero. If that is not a valid assumption, we can use this slightly longer version: (18 Keystrokes)

```
i <input> <esc>?[1-9]<enter>lD0d/<up><enter>
```

Comment: I don't think you need to include code to allow the user to input the numbers (`i` and `<esc>`). In vim golf the golfer starts with the input already in a file loaded the buffer and the cursor in the top left corner, but the user also has to save and exit (`ZZ` is usually the fastest way). Then you could do something like `d[1-9]<enter>$NlDZZ` (13 keystrokes). Note `N`/`n` instead of `/<up><enter>`

Answer (score 2):

### ES6, 51 bytes

```
f=a=>a.map(x=>x?t=++i:f<i++||++f,f=i=0)&&a.slice(f,t)
```

`t` is set to the index after the last non-zero value, while `f` is incremented as long as only zeros have been seen so far.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 23 bytes

```perl6
{.[.grep(?*):k.minmax]}
{.[minmax .grep(?*):k]}
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
# replace the built-in trim subroutine
# with this one in the current lexical scope
my &trim = {.[.grep(?*):k.minmax]}

say trim [0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0];
# (8 1 4 3 5 6 4 1 2)
say trim [0, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0];
# (4 1 2 0 1 2 4)
say trim [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
# ()
say trim [3, 4, 5, 0, 0];
# (3 4 5)
say trim [6];
# (6)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, 11 bytes

```
+`^0 ?| 0$
<empty>
```

Quite simple. Recursively replaces zeroes at beginning and end of line.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2BeMCA_fCAwJAo&input=MCAwIDA)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>56</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

Uses Windows-1252 encoding

String based solution

```
<?=preg_replace(~ÜÒ×ßÏÖÔƒ×ßÏÖÔÛÜ,"",join($argv,~ß));
```

Run like this:

```
echo '<?=preg_replace(~ÜÒ×ßÏÖÔƒ×ßÏÖÔÛÜ,"",join($argv,~ß));' | php -- 0 0 123 234 0 500 0 0 2>/dev/null;echo
```

If your terminal is set to UTF-8, this is the same:

```
echo '<?=preg_replace("#-( 0)+|( 0)+$#","",join($argv," "));' | php -- 0 0 123 234 0 500 0 0 2>/dev/null;echo
```

### Tweaks

- Saved 2 bytes by negating strings and dropping string delimiters
- Saved 2 bytes by using short print tag

Comment: Can you please provide an ASCII solution. Nobody can read this!

Comment: @Titus Sure. However, plenty of unreadable esolangs out there.... it's not like my answer doesn't feel right at home.

Comment: An array as first parameter of join?

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Yup. It's documented the other way around but it accepts both.

Comment: You are right I have not realize it

Comment: Wanted to point you at this: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15715/goodbye-world-complete-obfuscation. Can you create a score 0 answer in PHP?

Comment: @Titus I have a solution, but can't post it... I voted to reopen

Comment: @Titus: it probably won't be re-opened. Here you go (Windows 1252 encoding): `echo '<?="Äììçáúæ£Ôìñïç¢"^"ƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒ";' | php;echo`

Answer (score 2):

**Python, 84 characters**

```
def t(A):
 if set(A)<={0}:return[]
 for i in(0,-1):
  while A[i]==0:del A[i]
 return A
```

Comment: You can do `for i in-1,0:`

Comment: [I count 86 bytes.](//mothereff.in/byte-counter#def%20t%28A%29%3A%0A%20if%20set%28A%29%3C%3D%7B0%7D%3Areturn%5B%5D%0A%20for%20i%20in%280%2C-1%29%3A%0A%20%20while%20A%5Bi%5D%3D%3D0%3Adel%20A%5Bi%5D%0A%20return%20A)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>69</s> 67 bytes

```python
def f(a):
 for i in(0,-1):
  while a and a[i]==0:a.pop(i)
 return a
```

Comment: You can remove the space before your tuple in the second line.

Comment: You can do `for i in-1,0:`

Comment: Also, you might want to recount your bytes. I count 67 as is. You can also replace `[space][space]while` with `[tab]while`. And `==0` can be `<1`. https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#def%20f%28a%29%3A%0A%20for%20i%20in-1%2C0%3A%0A%09while%20a%20and%20a%5Bi%5D%3C1%3Aa.pop%28i%29%0A%20return%20a

Comment: [I count 67 bytes.](//mothereff.in/byte-counter#def%20f%28a%29%3A%0A%20for%20i%20in%280%2C-1%29%3A%0A%20%20while%20a%20and%20a%5Bi%5D%3D%3D0%3Aa.pop%28i%29%0A%20return%20a)

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript (ES6) 40 bytes

```
a=>/^(0,)*(.*?)(,0)*$/.exec(a.join())[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

## ///, 20 bytes

```
/[0 /[// 0]/]//[0]//
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L1swIC9bLy8gMF0vXS8vWzBdLy9bMCA0IDEgMiAwIDEgMiA0IDEwIDBd&input=)

Input as list of integers separated by spaces and surrounded by square brackets (`[0 1 2 3 4 5 0]`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 27 bytes

```
p->Vecrev(polrecip(Pol(p)))
```

When a list is converted to a polynomial, the leading zeros are removed. Then we can take the reciprocal polynomial, and convert it back to a list, and the trailing zeros are removed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#S1OwVfhfoGsXlppclFqmUZCfU5SanFmgEZCfo1Ggqan5v6AoM69EI00j2kBHAYIsdBQMdRRMdBSMdRRMdRTMwGygiBFMAQjFampyYWrFJmkM1m@KRcYMyPsPAA)

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <s>38</s> 32 bytes

```matlab
@(x)x((cummax(x))&cummax(x,'r'))
```

Anonymous function, saved to default output variable `Ans`.
Tried different ideas but the simplest stayed the shortest. Also I should note that instead of `cummmax` you can use `cumsum` as well.
Unfortunately, doesn't work with Octave, because its implementation of `cummax` and `cumsum` doesn't allow for reversing the direction. For Octave alternative solution below.

**How does it work?**

- `cummax(x)` takes cumulative maximal value, so everything besides leading zeros is greater than 0.
- `cummax(x,'reverse')` does the same but in reversed direction - everything besides trailing zeros is greater than 0.
- `&` is logical conjunction (AND) on arrays. Both numeric arrays (results of `cummax` functions) are transformed into logical arrays in a way that `0` is `false` and anything else is `true`.
- `cummax(x))&cummax(x,'reverse')` gives thus logical array with `true` for values we need to include and `false` for trailing/leading zeros.
- `x(cummax(x))&cummax(x,'reverse'))` performs logical indexing - only values where corresponding logical value is `true` are selected.
- `'reverse'` can be replaced simply with `'r'`

### Octave, 40 bytes

```matlab
@(x)x((cummax(x))&flip(cummax(flip(x))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCs0JDI7k0NzexAsjWVEvLySyA8cFsoKCm5v80BVuFxLxia640jWgDHQUIstBRMNRRMNFRMNZRMNVRMAOzgSJGMAUgFKsJ1YMsB2GYIEsbYGoyBisxRRYyi9X8DwA)
Basically the same as MATLAB solution, only `cummax(x,'reverse')` is replaced with `flip(cummax(flip(x)))` - the `x` is flipped, then `cummax` and then result is flipped.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 16 bytes

```
[ [ 0 = ] trim ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjUJxaWJqal5xarFBQlFpSUllQlJlXomDNxVXNpQAE1QoGYGihYKhgomCsYKpgBqQNFYyg4gYKtXB1MHEQaYIiY4Ch2hiowhRFxAzIqv0frRANFLNViFUoKcrMVYj9n5tYoFBckpicrfcfAA)

Factor has a combinator for this. You just have to supply it with a quotation that returns `t` for the element(s) you want to trim.

Answer (score 2):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 78 bytes

```
<>?@.#<...#)!j.(,2#_|...><.L/(,\@^_\L\.\.#\S.?S>S(.<)).7),..\._v..._|..._>#('0
```

[Try it on the online interpreter!](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/?i=%5B0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%208%2C%201%2C%204%2C%203%2C%205%2C%206%2C%204%2C%201%2C%202%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%5D#%3C%3E%3F%40.%23%3C...%23)!j.(%2C2%23_%7C...%3E%3C.L%2F(%2C%5C%40%5E_%5CL%5C.%5C.%23%5CS.%3FS%3ES(.%3C)).7)%2C..%5C._v..._%7C..._%3E%23(%270) Output is separated by newlines.

This is some of the control flow of all time.

```
           <
          > ?
         @ . #
        < . . .
       # ) ! j .
      ( , 2 # _ |
     . . . > < . L
    / ( , \ @ ^ _ \
   L \ . \ . # \ S .
  ? S > S ( . < ) ) .
 7 ) , . . \ . _ v . .
. _ | . . . _ > # ( ' 0
```

[image]

This is definitely the most colors I've had to use in this size of grid. Let's break this down:

The first loop -- red, blue, and yellow -- ignores input until it sees something other than `0`. If it reaches EOF before finding a positive value, the green path terminates the program with no output.

The next loop -- orange and yellow-green -- counts how much input there is after the first positive number.

The third loop -- cyan and brown -- removes zeroes from the end of the array and decreases the counter as it goes.

The final loop -- gray and red-violet -- prints out what's left. The purple branch terminates the program once it's exhausted the list.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 49 bytes

```
($args[0]-join',').trim(',0').trim('0,')-split','
```

Takes input `$args[0]` and `-join`s them together with commas to form a string. We then use the [`.Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) function called twice to remove first the trailing and then the leading zeros and commas. We then `-split` the string on commas back into an array.

---

*Alternate version, without using conversion*
**PowerShell, 81 bytes**

```
function f{param($a)$a=$a|%{if($_-or$b){$b=1;$_}};$a[$a.Count..0]}
f(f($args[0]))
```

Since PowerShell doesn't have a function to trim arrays, we define a new function `f` that will do half of this for us. The function takes `$a` as input, then loops through each item with a foreach loop `|%{...}`. Each iteration, we check a conditional for `$_ -or $b`. Since non-zero integers are truthy, but `$null` is falsey (and `$b`, being not previously defined, starts as `$null`), this will only evaluate to `$true` once we hit our first non-zero element in the array. We then set `$b=1` and add the current value `$_` onto the pipeline. That will then continue through to the end of the input array, with zeros in the middle and the end getting added onto the output, since we've set `$b` truthy.

We encapsulate and store the results of the loop all back into `$a`. Then, we index `$a` in reverse order (i.e., reversing the array), which is left on the pipeline and thus is the function's return value.

We call the function twice on the `$args[0]` input to the program in order to "trim" from the front, then the front again (which is the back, since we reversed). The order is preserved since we're reversing twice.

This version plays a *little* loose with the rules for an input array of all zeros, but since [ignoring STDERR](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/42963) is accepted practice, the program will spit out two (verbose) `Cannot index into a null array` errors to <sub>(PowerShell's equivalent of)</sub> STDERR and then output nothing.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
#/.{Longest[0...],x__,0...}->{x}&
```

Answer (score 1):

## jq, 48 characters

```
. as$a|map(.>0)|indices(1>0)|$a[min:(max//-1)+1]
```

Sample run:

(Command line option `-c` only used in this sample for readability to avoid pretty printing the result.)

```
bash-4.3$ jq -c '. as$a|map(.>0)|indices(1>0)|$a[min:(max//-1)+1]' <<< '[0, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0]'
[4,1,2,0,1,2,4]

bash-4.3$ jq -c '. as$a|map(.>0)|indices(1>0)|$a[min:(max//-1)+1]' <<< '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]'
[]
```

On-line test:

- [[0, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0]](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%20as$a|map%28.%3E0%29|indices%281%3E0%29|$a[min:%28max//-1%29%2B1]&j=[0,%204,%201,%202,%200,%201,%202,%204,%200])
- [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%20as$a|map%28.%3E0%29|indices%281%3E0%29|$a[min:%28max//-1%29%2B1]&j=[0,%200,%200,%200,%200,%200])

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 43 characters

```groovy
{x={it.dropWhile{it<1}.reverse()};x(x(it))}
```

Sample run:

```
groovy:000> ({x={it.dropWhile{it<1}.reverse()};x(x(it))})([0, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0])
===> [4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4]

groovy:000> ({x={it.dropWhile{it<1}.reverse()};x(x(it))})([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
===> []
```

Answer (score 1):

## sed, 24 bytes

```
#!/bin/sed -f
:
s/ 0$//
s/^0\b \?//
t
```

Input as space-separated words on stdin.

It cost me five bytes (`\b \?`) to deal with the special case of all zeros.

#### Test results

```
$ ./71877.sed <<EOF
0 0 0 8 1 4 3 5 6 4 1 2 0 0 0 0
0 4 1 2 0 1 2 4 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
3 4 5 0 0
6
EOF
8 1 4 3 5 6 4 1 2
4 1 2 0 1 2 4

3 4 5
6
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 134 bytes

```
using System.Linq;n=>string.Join(" ",n).Trim('0',' ').Split(new[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s=>int.Parse(s));
```

If I can return a comma separated string of the return values:

### C#, 36 bytes

```
n=>string.Join(",",n).Trim('0',',');
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 61 bytes

```
<?=preg_replace("^[^_]*_(0_)*(.*)(_0)*$","$2",join(_,$argv));
```

regexp using the underscore as delimiter.

Comment: `<?=preg_replace("#^[^_]*_(0_)*(.*?)(_0)*$#","$2",join(_,$argv));` works better for `$argv=["t.php",0, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0];` or you should take `<?=preg_replace("^[^_]*_(0_)*(.*?)(_0)*$","$2",join(_,$argv));` instead

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 41 Bytes

```
<?="[".trim(join(",",$_GET[a]),",0")."]";
```

If the input as array could be write as `?a=0&b=0` and so on it can be reduce to 38 Bytes

```
<?="[".trim(join(",",$_GET),",0")."]";
```

The longer way working with Regex 65 Bytes

```
<?="[".preg_replace("#^(0,)*|(,0)*$#","",join(",",$_GET[a]))."]";
```

Comment: Invalid, consider input: `0 10`, output `[1]`

Comment: @aross in the question is to read non-negative integers like this: followed with no integer greater then 9. let me remenber you to your own opinion at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94832/yes-of-course-im-an-adult/94842#94842 You are right if there could been an integer greater then 10 my answer is not valid

Comment: The other challenge *explicitly* specified a range of input. Though I only just realized that this challenge doesn't clarify that (someone asked about it on OP). Usually it's safe to assume that there's no limit if none is posted though...

Comment: Normally this would be considered **optimizing for the specified test-cases** which is a [loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2507/38392).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 30 bytes

```
<?=trim(join(' ',$argv),' 0');
```

Needs to be saved in a file called '0' (or any number of 0s). Works with all test cases (which are <10 at time of submission) but if a test case with a final non 0 integer of 10 (or any other integer with a 0 units digit) gets added then it will no longer be valid.

use like:

```
php 0 0 4 1 2 0 1 2 4 0
```

Where the first 0 is the file name and the rest is the input

A bunch of answers got added between me loading the challenge and submitting this. I'd delete it but I never finished the account sign up, would a mod do so please?

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

Built-in version. :)

```
0Ú
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4PCs//@jDXQUIMhCR8FQR8FER8FYR8EULGIG5gIFjWBqQCgWAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 22 bytes

```
p
\A2
~R
(#
~*
\
/
+
i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyalMyyzO@P@/gCvG0YirLohLQ5mrTosrhkufS5sr8///aAMFELRQMFQwUTBWMFUwA9KGCkYKEHGDWAA)

### Explanation

```
p   print the result of:
\A2 repeat the following twice:
~R  compose reverse with the below
(#  filter the elements of the input by the following function:
~*  compose sign with:
\   map each prefix to:
/    fold by:
+    addition
i   evaluated input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 24 bytes

```
gsub(/^(0 )*|( *0)*$/,e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/vbg0SUM/TsNAQVOrRkNBy0BTS0VfJ1Xz/38DBRMFQwUjBQMwaaJgwGWgAIdcxkARUzDLjAsA)

Using a convenient input to awk's default field separator (space). No easy way to define an array here.

This substitutes every match to the regex `/^(0 )*|( *0)*$/` for a null string (variable `e`, not defined). Even if there are no trailing zeros, null matches are found before and after the input, so gsub() always returns a positive number, and the input (modified or not) is printed.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2/3, 48 bytes

```python
lambda x:map(int,''.join(map(str,x)).strip('0'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRocIqN7FAIzOvREddXS8rPzNPA8QvLinSqdDU1APSmQUa6gbqmpr/ExVsFaINdBQgyEJHwVBHwURHwVhHwVQHKGAG5gHFjGBKQCiWq6AIaLiGVppGItAMAA)

Comment: Realized after posting that Adam Abahot posted an identical answer (excluding the name)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ã fÎfÌ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=4yBmzmbM&input=WzAsIDQsIDEsIDIsIDAsIDEsIDIsIDQsIDBdCi1R)

```
2Æ=Ôf|
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=MsY91GZ8&input=WzAsIDQsIDEsIDIsIDAsIDEsIDIsIDQsIDBdCi1R)

Answer (score 1):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s Type System, 69 bytes

```
type T<R>=R extends[...infer K,0]?T<K>:R extends[0,...infer K]?T<K>:R
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgPAJQHwF4FQgD2BAdgEwGcBtAOnIEtcAzCAJygGkAaABgF0B%20eRpALnRYcBEq2blSVWg0Zce-BAG4AUMoD0aqDkLAoAYwCGhCIVWhIUAIJQUsOMQCMzKACZnHJOs1QoAPU5m4NAAQjZ2xGJQkZEAHM5OUAAszgDMzgCszgBszslQCW5R7sVR7J4aPn4ByubQAMJh8BG58c6FkQUtpeXeVYEWACKN9tElo91elf790ACiw8RpSRljZZM%200zVBUABiC1lrFRvVtVAA4sMARNrAlz1TnEA)

### Explanation

By using `infer`, we can take out portions of the array that don't start or end in 0 recursively:

```
type T<R> = 
    R extends [...infer K, 0] ? T<K> : // take out trailing zeros
    R extends [0, ...infer K] ? T<K> : // and leading zeros
    R; // if none are left, return the final array.
```

Since we use `extends`, we don't need to bind the input parameters to a type (e.g. using `T<"input">` simply returns `"input"`)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 58 bytes

Not the best JS answer, but a different approach not using regexp, replace, nor filter.
(Like other answers, we assume that the array input can only contain integers <= 9)

```javascript
t=>(r=(g=a=>[...""+a.reverse().join``*1])(g(t)))[0]*1?r:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5daoQwFIXfZxWSp9wxDdr5YRiI89w1hMAEJyMOYiRG6Qb6VugG2gV0W27EGnXaymgCCZxz7nfuTdayjE1a2KdcX1R7Za1lETYMJ0yyiFNKEfIlNapWplQY6E2n@fm8DgXgBFsA4IFYhydz5KJdqVpmlbSK4TQvKkvUa6Fiqy4kznSuXpzGHLN3BTGqrDLLrkMagEWxzkudKZrpBOPBHhsZY3faqJxQ8/mGjqj5ekfgI48j/6/GR8JrPr6dOGA6AcHqd0Ps8YC4eyAh2ZIN2ZF994fkmQx6IDzi8QdXeDBl3Gfcu3VT09MxJonBh8c9xs650zFmjAlj03Xvlgk9o8@IZcZ@afYfYyYD7Q8)

---

Converts the array into a number to get rid of the leading zeros.

Then we do this a second time on the reversed array to get rid of the leading (previously trailing) zeros, and reverse back again to get the answer array in the correct order.

The case were the array contains only zeros had to be specifically handled (or else it would have resulted in a `[0]` output), and this part has a **cost of 14 bytes** :(

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 73 bytes

```
(λ(l)(define(g k)(if(= 0(car k))(g(cdr k))k))(reverse(g(reverse(g l)))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define f
  (λ(l)
    (define (g k)                     ; fn to remove leading zeros; 
        (if(= 0 (first k))
           (g (rest k))
           k))
    (reverse (g (reverse (g l))))))
```

Last line removes leading 0s in original and reversed list. List is re-reversed to get original order.

Testing with different combinations:

```
(f '(0 0   2 5 0 6 8 9   0 0))
(f '(0 0 0 2 5 0 6 8 9   0 0 0))

(f '(0 0 0 2 5 0 6 8 9   0 0))
(f '(0 0   2 5 0 6 8 9   0 0 0))

(f '(0 0   2 5 0 6 8 9))
(f '(0 0 0 2 5 0 6 8 9))

(f '(2 5 0 6 8 9   0 0))
(f '(2 5 0 6 8 9   0 0 0))

(f '(2 5 0 6 8 9))
```

Output:

```
'(2 5 0 6 8 9)
'(2 5 0 6 8 9)
'(2 5 0 6 8 9)
'(2 5 0 6 8 9)
'(2 5 0 6 8 9)
'(2 5 0 6 8 9)
'(2 5 0 6 8 9)
'(2 5 0 6 8 9)
'(2 5 0 6 8 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <strike>144</strike> 126 chars

- -18 chars thanks to [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

It's a bit longer than the other PHP answers because it's array-based.

```
function e($a){foreach($a as$i=>$v){if($v)break;unset($a[$i]);}return array_reverse($a);}print_r(e(e(explode(",",$argv[1]))));
```

Call like this: `php remove0.php 0,4,2,1,0,1,2,4,0`

Example return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 4
)
```

Comment: Rearranged it a bit to reduce it to 126 characters, without changing the logic: http://pastebin.com/HMSGfftE

Comment: @manatwork thanks, changed it.

Comment: According to discussion in [Running PHP with `-r` instead of code tags](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/running-php-with-r-instead-of-code-tags) and [Is the PHP opening tag mandatory in byte count?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/is-the-php-opening-tag-mandatory-in-byte-count), running code with `php -r` is acceptable, so no need the `<?`.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks, changed it ^^

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>48</s> <s>55</s> <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```
print(input().strip('0 '))
```

Input and output is taken as space-separated numbers, eg:

```
0 0 0 1 3 1 4 0 1 3 6 4 5 19 3 1 4 0
```

Alternatively, a 29-byte Python 2 solution:

```
print raw_input().strip('0 ')
```

Comment: This chops off trailing 0s from numbers divisible with 10: `python3 -c "print(input().strip('0 '))" <<< '0 2000 0'`.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 54 bytes

```javascript
s=>(g=a=>a.filter(e=>e^k?k=1:k,k=0).reverse(),g(g(s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7hCsIwDIT/7ynKEGwgjk43EaXzQUrFIlmdm5u0ZX/EZ59OJiqEEO67O3IxvfEnV93Cot8MpRy8LLiVRhYmKasmkOMkCzrU@1qm2xprKSBx1JPzxAEtt9wDwHDqWt81lDSd5XMfjAtz2EUqYkoJZBmyFNkSmfgcL0VoZHGGKS5RvHcWa5wCfzP62i6cq9ZOjtW7IP/iFWaYT3A9CutYRzq5mhsnJgv2@95xdi85KaHhMaLZnVSqH0eAaHgC)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 52 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,q=f(s,s))=>q.filter(e=>e^k?k=1:k,k=0).reverse()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7rCoJAEIX/@xSLCO3CJOuliGLtQZYNRUYzzcvu4h/p2S3DqGA4DOc7c5hbNmYm11Vvt@NhngtBDQyieKlhTCSDX1SNRU1RJHipz7UIjjXUgjNf44jaIGVz3rWma9BvupJujM203bCTIx0iJQcSAwmAhED4Z3k5XAFxYwggBP7W2FWwHvzNkms7e63ack1E74LdF0cQw26F@8XYu8pR/j3rKRKRkN/3Um8qKEqu2GNB3oQyUI@UMWd@Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
0P
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIwUCIsIiIsIiJd)

What it says on the box. Stri`P`s `0`s.

Comment: AKA "cyclops sticking its tongue out"

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>80</s> 78 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) by using `strlen()` and indexing into the string

```c
p;f(char*s){for(;*s&&*s<49;s++);for(p=strlen(s);p&&s[p]<49;s[p--]=0);puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RisIwEEXf@xUDQklqKlW7osT6I6UPNU1roBtDJvVF/PaYxF0QZoa5596BEeUkhPeGj0TcelsgfY53S3iBeV7guT5xXK8pj8w06OwsNUHKTZ5ja7rkt6Ysu6YKcHEYzZdfKS3mZZBwRjfM6rq5XbJvZpWeIlPawW@vNIlLbyfBIH4BRdgfbUezJwBkof9wuIQGwhwWQ1Jm21GeAmmMJHgBfISV8ltb6RaroeLZy/uKwaeODLYMagZ7Bj@JHJIMcPefifUG)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 15 bytes

```julia
~x=strip(x,'0')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CtrikKLNAo0JH3UBd8/9/h8Ti4tSiEgUlAxNDIwNDIxMDJQVbWwUlKE@JC6EADCCySMLGJqYwUSATScIMImimBAA)

Accepts a `String` input.

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 10 bytes

```
⌈`∘×⊸/∘⌽⍟2
```

Anonymous tacit function; takes a list, returns a list. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oyIYOKImMOX4oq4L+KImOKMveKNnzIKCkYgMOKAvzDigL804oC/MeKAvzLigL8w4oC/MeKAvzLigL80MOKAvzAK)

#### Explanation

```
⌈`∘×⊸/∘⌽⍟2
      ∘⌽    Reverse the list; then,
    ⊸/      select the elements matching the 1s in the following list:
   ×         Get the sign of each number in the list (0 or 1)
⌈`∘          Scan by maximum: preserves leading 0s, but turns all others into 1s
            All but the leading run of zeros is therefore kept
        ⍟2  Do this twice
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 101 bytes

```python
def f(l,n,a=0):
 while l[a]==0:
  del l[a];a+=1;n-=1
 a=n-1
 while l[a]==0:
  del l[a];a-=1
 return l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI0cnTyfR1kDTikuhPCMzJ1UhJzox1tbWAMhXSEnNAXOtE7VtDa3zdG0NuRQSbfN0DfGqBSsrSi0pLcpTyPn/HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 21 bytes

```
\[0,?/[/,?0]/]/#input
```

A very simple solution consisting of two regexes, each stripping 0's from the start and end respectively.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/PybaQMdeP1pfx94gVj9WXzkzr6C05P9/oKiJjqGOkY4BmDTRMYjlAorBIZhnDBQ3hfLMYgE)