# Divide one number by another

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

### Challenge

Given two numbers, output their quotient. In other words, integer divide one number by another.

Both divisor/dividend will be under 10001. Division must be performed using integer division, rounding down.

Here are some example inputs and outputs:

```
5       1       5
-4      2       -2
4       -2      -2
6       2       3
16      4       4
36      9       4
15      2       7
17      3       5
43      5       8
500     5       100
500     100     5
10000   2       5000
```

Or as CSV:

```
5,1,5
-4,2,-2
4,-2,-2
6,2,3
16,4,4
36,9,4
15,2,7
17,3,5
43,5,8
500,5,100
500,100,5
10000,2,5000
```

### Rules

- Standard loopholes not allowed
- You must use integer division, not floating point division
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer wins, but will not be selected.
- The second input (denominator) will never be equal to `0`.

### Why?

I'm interested in seeing answers in esoteric languages, like Brainfuck and Retina. Answers in regular languages will be trivial, however I would really like to see answers in these languages.

I will be giving a bounty of **+50** reputation to a Retina answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiply two numbers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/multiply-two-numbers)

Comment: @ГригорийПерельман THis is differennt. integer multiplication does not translate well into integer division

Comment: Closely related: [Division and remainder](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114003/division-and-remainder)

Comment: @LuisMendo No remainder, expanded number range

Comment: Can we assume input is not 0?

Comment: @ГригорийПерельман Yes

Comment: Can we take input in binary or unary, or must it be decimal?

Comment: @ETHproductions Decimal.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Yes, this could only be considered a dupe for languages which have an easy way to perform multiplication and integer division (then again, that's most languages...)

Comment: Do we need to handle negative numbers? None of the test cases are negative, but the question only specifies denominator != 0.

Comment: Well, good luck getting a valid answer in BF. It's easy for positive integers, but negatives aren't possible without taking input as strings or something ugly.

Comment: You just invalidated almost all the interesting approaches...

Comment: -1 Challenge is lame when negatives are required.

Comment: The whole reason that the division and remainder challenge was on a restricted number range is because that allows more languages to compete.

Comment: That's why there's a Retina bounty...

Comment: I would recommend to allow people to use any base such as unary (if you want Retina/esoteric solutions), and only supply positive integers as input (for a similar reason).

Comment: I can't tell you the reason for the other downvotes, but mine is because I firmly believe that trivial questions like this are bad for the site.

Comment: -1 _Challenge is lame when negatives are required_ as noted by @mbomb007, AND test cases were all positive!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 11 bytes

JavaScript doesn't have integers but using a [bitwise or](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.10) parses a float as a signed 32 bit integer.

```
a=>b=>a/b|0
```

## Try it online

```js
const f = a=>b=>a/b|0
alert(f(prompt())(prompt()))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 8 bytes

```
Quotient
```

Thanks to @JungHwanMin for reminding me there's a builtin.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```python
int.__div__
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@ZV6IXH5@SWRYf/7@gCMhTSNMwMdax0PwPAA)

Answer (score 2):

## C (GCC), 13 bytes

Doesn't work on *all* implementations, but that's OK.

```c
f(a,b){a/=b;}
```

[Try it on TIO!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@mkaiTpFmdqG@bZF37PzcxM09Ds7qgKDOvJE1DSTVFSSdNw9BUx0hTEygLAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 8 bytes

```
::?a'\`b
```

## Explanation:

```
::    get a and b from the cmd line
?     Print
a \ b the backslash does integer division, (opposed to the forward slash / for float div)
  ' ` however, the same symbol is used for ELSE. We need to escape it with ' and `
```

---

Note that the latest version of QBIC allows for an inline use of the `:` function, saving two bytes:

```
?:'\`:
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 4 bytes

```
a//b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@5@or5/0//9/Q/P/xgA)

Explanation:

```
      A and B are read implicitly from the cmd line
a//b  Calculate the int div of a and b (double slash == int div)
      Results of the last expression are printed implicitly.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 3 bytes

```
q~/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19Yp///v7GZgiUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [아희(Aheui)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Aheui), 15 bytes

```
방방나망희
```

[Try it here! (please copy and paste the code manually)](http://jinoh.3owl.com/aheui/jsaheui_en.html)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, <s>25</s> <s>22</s> 15 bytes

```
echo $(($1/$2))
```

Save to script, input numbers given at command line

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @betseg

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf StackExchange! Nice first answer. Also, you can remove the space after the semicolon and the spaces inside parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 6 bytes

```
riri/p
```

```
ri takes input as integer
/ does integer division
p prints it
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//78osyhTv@D/f0NzLmMA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 23 Bytes

```
<?=$argv[1]/$argv[2]^0;
```

or

```
<?=$argv[1]/$argv[2]|0;
```

and for 29 Bytes

```
<?=intdiv($argv[1],$argv[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/1//9/Q/P/xgA)

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, 3 bytes

`II÷`

[Try online](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@/peXj7//@GBiDAZQQA)

If you can reverse the input, it would work in 1 byte: `÷`

Answer (score 1):

## [Decimal](//git.io/Decimal), 12 bytes

```
81D81D44D301
```

Ungolfed:

```
81D   ; builtin 1 - read INT to stack
81D   ; builtin 1 - read INT to stack
44D   ; math divide (postfix /)
301   ; print from stack to output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNzsxNzPn/38LQBYhMTFyMDQz//7dUMAYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 6 bytes

```
$.$%_<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/X0VPRTXe5v9/CwVdo/8A)

Formats into this triangle:

```
  $
 . $
% _ <
```

Without directionals and no-ops, the code looks like this: `$$_%`

- `$` - read input as integer
- `_` - divide
- `%` - print

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 28 bytes

```
\d+
*
~`(_+) (_+)
K`$1$nC`$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyZFm0uLqy5BI15bUwFEcHknqBiq5DknqBj9/29ppmAOAA)

I'm quite new to Retina; I probably could have golfed this more.

**Explanation:**

Let's start with an input: `38 4`

```
\d+
*
```

This turns the numbers into unary, so 4 is represented as ____, and 38 with 38 underscores.

```
~`...
```

This marks a stage that generates code to run afterwards

```
(_+) (_+)
K`$1$nC`$2
```

This is a replace stage to generate the division code; Firstly, it splits the string into the dividend (referenced as $1) and divisor (referenced as $2). Then, it returns the string:

```
K`{dividend as unary}
C`{divisor as unary}
```

The returned string is evaluated and the answer implicitly printed. It sets the working string to the dividend, and counts the matches of the divisor in it.

Comment: 20 bytes after golfing: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/vy5BT1tBQ09bk8s7QUVNK/7QNhVDrf//Lc0UzAE "Retina – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice! I'd completely forgotten about this but that's an interesting golf

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/), 3 bytes

```
¿¿/
```

Simply 2 nice inputs and then divides them.

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N////0P5D@/X//zfkMgYA)

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 16 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a%1/%2
```

`set/a` doesn't print its output inside a batch script, so we have to fake it out by starting a new copy of the command processor.

Answer (score 0):

## GML, 30 bytes

```
return argument0 div argument1
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 6 bytes

```
Input :iPart(X/Y
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```
\d+
*
(-?)(_+);(-?)(\2)*_*
$1$3$#4
--
```

Takes input in the format `denominator;numerator`. Also works for negative integers after the specs got changed, unlike the existing Retina answer.

-2 bytes thanks to *@FryAmTheEggman* thanks to a golf suggested in [another Retina answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190623/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##JYk7CsMwEET7uYYVkGQWdvXFbJHSlzA4gaRIkyLk/sqiTPHmDfN5fl/vu4yL32/jeKyI8HQN/lyDTjlSiGeEE5fdUkCEMUQrkpKtpMWsoag0bJqbLanIKh1VSzZUZgjzbDvZgq5bA012pb9b/QA)

**Explanation:**

Convert all numbers in the input to unary, replacing them with that amount of underscores:

```
\d+
*
```

Integer divide the two unary numbers (but with a decimal numbers as result), and filter all `-` to the front at the same time:

```
(-?)(_+);(-?)(\2)*_*
$1$3$#4
```

Remove any `--` if present:

```
--
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 2 bytes

```
:/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWi6z0IYwVBQpu0RY6xrEQ7oIFEBoA)

Answer (score -1):

### Ruby, 10 bytes

```
->i,j{i/j}
```

Extremely simple. Lambda function that returns the value `i/j`.

Comment: -1, if an answer is extremely short and boring with just the code, you should add a link, or an explanation, or a comment on the code or *something* other than `My answer's really boring, so blah blah blah`.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Fixed