# Couch 2048: How much more till 2048?

Tags: code-golf

I have just tried a game called [Couch 2048](https://js13kgames.com/games/couch-2048/index.html).
(Note: You should have a look to better understand this question.)
Since it wasn't very exciting for me, I've been asking myself *'How much more till 2048!?'*
That inspired me to post a challenge, because calculating this in not as easy as I thought.

**Your goal:**
Given a list of balls on the sofa, you have to output how many balls with a value of 2 have to fall from the sky so that one can win the game (by reaching the 2048 ball).

- Assume the input is valid.
- Assume the player won't drop any balls.
- Assume the balls which fall from the sky always have a value of 2, as I've said.
- Valid output examples: 3, "4", [5], ["6"]

**Edit:**
I should clarify something:
 - You have to print the *smallest* amount of 2s needed.

**Test cases:**
`[2048] -> 0` You've already won
`[1024,1024] -> 0` You don't need any more balls to win
`[1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2] -> 1` One ball required to *'activate the chain'*
`[512] -> 768`
`[512,2] -> 767`
`[4,16,64] -> 982`

**Notes**:
I'm not a native speaker - Tell me if you spotted a typo or some non-grammatical text.
If something's unclear, ask in comments.

Comment: why `[4,16,64] -> 22`?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. It looks like this challenge is: add all the elements in the array, subtract from `2048` and divide by `2` - if so, you might want to double check the last test case - if not, please use it as an example to explain why the output isn't `982`.

Comment: @Shaggy thx for noticing a silly mistake

Comment: Hi there. I took the liberty of fixing some grammar/spelling mistakes. I saw your note at the bottom. :) You can take a look at the changed I did, and if anything is incorrect, feel free to revert or edit again. Regardless of the grammar/spelling, it's a nice first challenge, so +1 from me. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: Thx @KevinCruijssen

Comment: Woah, I haven't thought my first challenge will have 7 answers and 2 upvotes in the first hour! And I reached to ~28 people!

Comment: @micnap It's expected for easy challenges to get many answers, but don't make it too trivial, [like this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123808/test-if-two-numbers-are-equal?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Can there be a number being 1, not a power of 2 or larger than 2048 to be in the input? (I don't play the game)

Comment: It don't want to blame Kevin Cruijssen but his comment may have had accelerated the answer influx.

Comment: @user202729 no. Just 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048

Comment: Hey, downvoter: explain your point of view! It's necessary for the challenge to improve!

Comment: @micnap Usually it's because they don't like the challenge. /// It's not recommended to leave such comments, which may be observed as vote manipulation.

Answer (score 11):

## Java 8, 17 bytes

```java
s->1024-s.sum()/2
```

Port of [*@LuisFelipeDeJesusMunoz*' JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175769/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fZDBTsMwDIbvewofE8k1a8iqShO778AuOyIOoctQSptOizsJoT17SUKFgElcrNj@8v@2W3MxRXt4m5rOhACPxvmPBYDzbM9H01jYpRRyBRrRRpxGdh0FPlvT09bzPr/AyXUkr4sYAht2DezAw8MUik25VLoIFMZeyDs1rRNzGl@6yMzoZXAH6KO5iGrOvz49g5FfzmwDC7XUddaf86SIKdwUV6VCtaqwVDVWGu8VlhXWqFH9RCP1J/3d1@lXpW9WynNmIt6DiL6n3L8Htj0NI9MpLsCdF57@uxcNR2GknB2u0yc)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->           // Method with IntStream parameter and int return-type
  1024-       //  Return 1024, minus:
   s.sum()    //   The sum of the input-IntStream
          /2  //   Divided by 2
```

Comment: That feeling when Java is beating both python(because lambda syntax) and javascript(because sum)

Answer (score 8):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 72 bytes

```
({{}})({<({}[()()])>()}{})([{}]((((((((()()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){}){})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6urZWU6PaRqO6NlpDU0MzVtNOQ7O2GigWXV0bqwEDmhCoCZTAiv7/N1EwNFMwMwEA)

```
({{}})                     # Sum entire stack
      (                  ) # Push:
       {<          >()}{}  #   The number of times you can...
         ({}[()()])        #   Subtract 2 before reaching 0

([{}]                                        ) # Subtract that from...
     ((((((((()()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){}){}  # 1024
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm interested in learning Brain-Flak and your explanation was useful.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 22 bytes

```python
lambda x:4**5-sum(x)/2
```

Y'know, I *just* realized that `4**5` is the same length as `1024`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfaBvzPycxNyklUaHCykRLy1S3uDRXo0JT3@h/QVFmXolGoka0oYGRiY6poZGOkamZjqGRhY6ZiY6xkY6hmY6FjomOUaymJhdcrQlI2MwEKPYfAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/create_explanation.py), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
Σc/◘+
```

First MathGolf answer. :)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///c4mT9R9NnaP//H21qaKRjFAsA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7X314TaGSwqO2SQpKhf/PLU7WfzR9hvb/gv/R0UYGJhaxOtGGBkYmOiACxjY1NNIxMjXTMTSy0DEz0TE20jE007HQMdExAqoASkJIMM8EJGVmEhsLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Σ         # Sum of the (implicit) input-list
 c/       # Divide it by -2
   ◘+     # Add 1024 to it (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
O;žBα
```

Port of [*@LuisFelipeDeJesusMunoz*' JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175769/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f3/roPqdzG///jzY1NNIxigUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRf@d/f@ug@p3Mb/@v8j442MjCxiNVRiDY0MDLRARFwjqmhkY6RqZmOoZGFjpmJjrGRjqGZjoWOiY4RSAlQFkpB@CYgWTOT2FgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
O        # Sum of the (implicit) input-list
 ;       # Halved
  žB     # Push 1024
    α    # Absolute difference between the two (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 25 bytes

Based on [@Shaggys' comment and answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175768/78039)

*-3 bytes from @Arnauld =D*

```javascript
_=>1024-eval(_.join`+`)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BDoMgEETv/RKIq5XtSrjoj5hGicVGQ9imNv4@lqvByxxm3sysdrfb9F0@vzLwy8W5jUPbqRqpdLv1YqhWXsJYjPKOceKwsXeV57eYRY81maeUt5OdypDkKmsUAjYaFBrQBA8EpcEAAWYafzjvZmlKUzo9xwM)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes

```apl
2÷⍨2048-+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3@jw9ke9K4wMTCx0tfX/pz1qm/Cot8/wUVfzofXGj9omPuqbGhzkDCRDPDyD/6cpGGkZGnKBKQMFQwMw61HP3ke9m6EcSwipAFFkpGCiYAYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
2048-:@-+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBCoMwFEXReVZxcSJFTZPvN4SA0L2UhuLEgWPXHrUg1cnj8jhTyctocSRcEaexS6@ueZaHqSx1Hm1Ny5rIizGf93cmc6izvRP9ze0YvCBDwEskKL3gAxFFTraLS/5/PWTQsgE)

### Alternative:

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
1024-1#.-:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvLCoMwFAX3@YrBLqSgIff2GkLArxFD6caFa789PkDabg7DMOdTyzp6AplQJaj18vB9rk/XeNoy@paOLVNW5@bpvVDQYOnm83HNnxhE0SEimojGS5FIwtA7O4of/Ho7y2h1Bw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```ruby
->l{1024-l.sum/2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6n2tDAyEQ3R6@4NFffqPZ/gUJadDRISMfU0EjHyNRMx9DIQsfMRMfYSMfQTMdCx0THKDaWC6zMBCRiZhIb@x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Catholicon](https://github.com/okx-code/Catholicon), 5 bytes

```
-`L̇½Ṗ
```

Explanation:

```
-      subtract
 `L̇    1024
       from
   ½   half of the
    Ṗ  sum [of the input]
```

Comment: Is that a new golfing language I smell? :)

Comment: +1 for the new language. Another one to learn </sigh>

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 8 bytes

```
4^5-.5sum(Ans
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
xz nH²
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=eHogbkiy&input=WzEwMjQsNTEyLDI1NiwxMjgsNjQsMzIsMTYsOCw0LDJd) or [verify all test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=eHogbkiy&input=WwpbMjA0OF0sClsxMDI0LDEwMjRdLApbMTAyNCw1MTIsMjU2LDEyOCw2NCwzMiwxNiw4LDQsMl0sCls1MTJdLApbNTEyLDJdLApbNCwxNiw2NF0KXQotbVI=)

```
 z         :(Floor) divide each by 2
x          :Reduce by addition
   n       :Subtract from
    H      : 32
     ²     : Squared
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 28 bytes

```
a=>a.map(n=>x-=n/2,x=1024)|x
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETv@ZIEtrVZt6GXzY@EHEJtRalJaUVy8N@jUfEyw@MNzDU8wj5ul/XexHSayswlsA3tLawyss0NxwNCZt0hqWcuY4p7WqZ2SWfphMOOBg/CVQ01/tBrBOwNaBzAEBwRtIEBCLBO3vZXX6ZqDXnhP8@Z7SyzUqq8AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
HSạ⁽¡ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98j@OGuhY8a9x5aeHj5////o010DM10zExiAQ)

**Explanation:**

```
HSạ⁽¡ç    Example input: [4,16,64]
H         Halve input. [2, 8, 32]
 S        Sum. 42
   ⁽¡ç    Number 1024.
  ạ       Difference. 982
```

<sub>-1 byte by using a base-250 number</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## perl -aE, 27 bytes

```
$"=$:;say eval"(2048-@F)/2"
```

This reads a line with numbers (whitespace separated) from `STDIN`, and writes the answer to `STDOUT`.

What it does is subtract all the numbers from the input from 2048, and it divides the remainder by 2. The `-a` switch puts the in the array `@F` (one number per element). If we interpolate an array into a string (which is what we are doing here), perl puts the value of `$"` between the elements. The little used variable `$:` is be default `\n-`; and since white space between tokens is ignored, the result is subtracting all the numbers from 2048. The `eval` does the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
∑k¦ε½
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%91k%C2%A6%CE%B5%C2%BD&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
∑     # Sum
 k¦   # 2048
   ε  # Abs. diff.
    ½ # halved
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 33 bytes

```javascript
a=>!a.map(n=>x-=n/2,x=1024)>x?0:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BDsIgFET3vYU7SH4rfCkhJuBBCAtSW6Op0Fhj/u1R1E03M5mZt5hbfMV1eFyXZ5vyeSyTLdG6XezucWHJOmpt2iOQlQIVd3QSRypDTmuex27OF@Ybj0KZAI2vCFTZhG3TSwTsNUg0oBUcEKQGAwqwIp/1b7@s6qpVaML3D1k3MeKclzc)

Why you don't do on `[1024,1024,1024]`?

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 17 bytes

```r
4^5-sum(scan())/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3yTOVLe4NFejODkxT0NTU9/ovwmXoRmXmQnXfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [TeaScript](https://teascript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), 11 bytes

```javascript
4p5)-(xx)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/?code=x.r(R(x%5B0%5D%2C%27gi%27)%2C%27%27)&input=Test)#?code=%224p5)-(xx)%2F2%22&inputs=%5B%22%5B1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2%5D%22%5D&opts=%7B%22ev%22:true,%22debug%22:false,%22nox%22:true%7D)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ë3i─♠÷
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=893369c406f6&i=[2048]%0A[1024,1024]%0A[1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2]%0A[512]%0A[512,2]%0A[4,16,64]&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 12 bytes

```perl6
1024-*.sum/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvw39DAyERXS6@4NFff6L81V3FipUKaRrSRgYlFrCacC1KkAyLQxUwNjXSMTM10DI0sdMxMdIyNdAzNdCx0THSMkFQCFaHyUGRNQFrMQCb/BwA)

Anonymous Whatever lambda that takes a list and returns a number.

Answer (score 0):

## AWK, 26 bytes

```
{s+=$1}END{print 1024-s/2}
```

Input numbers are separated by newlines (i.e. one per line)

Answer (score 0):

## Neim, 6 bytes

Pretty new to Neim but got it working

```
ᚺςᚫᛦ
```

Explanation:

```
           : Sum input
   ᚺ        : Divide by 2 (stack now [input summed and divided by 2])
    ς       : Variable set to 16 pushed to stack
     ᚫ      : Multiply by 2
      ᛦ     : Square (stack now [input summed and divided by 2, 1024])
           : Subtract then absolute
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9uZWlt///wnZCs4Zq6z4Lhmqvhm6bwnZWk//9bMTAyNCA1MTIgMjU2IDEyOCA2NCAzMiAxNiA4IDQgMl0)

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA,  30 bytes**

```
2048-IntStream.of(a).sum()/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [RAD](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad), 10 bytes

```
1024-+/ω÷2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pM@f/f0MDIRFdb/3zn4e1G////N9IyUjBRMAMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 24 bytes

```clj
#(- 1024(/(apply + %)2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BCoMwFET3nmJAhB@KmPx@Q@4iLqQ10BJskHbh6aPpso3bmfdmbuH1/KxzSjW1MJqFOppiDBsuaBQrleg@e3ic9aqiuD6Wd1hAHgNrceNvmL2vXG56w@DewrCDFVwZxsJBwH/8gZayAil5xObHtAM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 16 bytes

```hs
(1024-).(/2).sum
```

An anonymous function, takes a list and returns a float.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BVkHD0MDIRFdTT0PfSFOvuDT3f25iZh5QvKAoM69EQUUhTSEapEJHwdTQSEfByNRMR8HQyEJHwQwoZAwUMQQKALlAnlHsfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## F#, 24 bytes

```
fun f->1024-List.sum f/2
```

1024 minus the sum divided by 2.